# Calculating count of numbers with average greater than x

Tags: c#, optimization, average

we have a input string such as "456,678,4599,87567"
need to find the count of numbers where average of the comma separated number's digit is greater than a number x.
Here is my working program for this problem.wanted to know if any one can suggest a more optimized code or a better optimized approach to this problem.i'm using c# code

```
public static int test(string i2,int limit)
    {
        int count=0;
        int i;
        int len = 0;
        Int32 sum;
        char[] tm={'{','}'};
        i2 = i2.Trim(tm);
        string[] w = i2.Split(',');
        len = w.Length;
        while (len-- > 0)
        {
                i=0;
                sum = 0;

                while (i < w[len].Length)
                {
                    sum += w[len][i] - '0';
                    i++;
                }
                if (sum / i >= limit)
                    count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Five consecutive questions, all more or less the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
var result = input.Trim('{', '}')
                  .Split(',')
                  .Count(num => num.Average(ch => ch - '0') >= limit);
```

Comment: Depends in what you're optimizing for.